# Keras LSTM trained with masking and custom loss function breaks after first iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, masking

I am attempting to train an LSTM that reads a variable length input sequence and has a custom loss function applied to it. In order to be able to train on batches, I pad my inputs to all be the maxmimum length.

My input data is a float tensor of shape (7789, 491, 11) where the form is (num_samples, max_sequence_length, dimension).
Any sample that is shorter than the maximum length I pad with -float('inf'), so a sequence with 10 values would start with 481 sets of 11 '-inf' values followed by the real values at the end.

The way I am attempting to evaluate this model doesn't fit into any standard loss functions, so I had to make my own. I've tested it and it performs as expected on sample tensors. I don't believe this is the source of the issue so I won't go into details, but I could be wrong.

The problem I'm having comes from the model itself. Here is how I define and train it:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-float('inf'), 
    input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30), 
    kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((3, 10)))

model.compile(loss=batched_custom_loss, optimizer='rmsprop', run_eagerly=True)

model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_y, validation_data=val, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

No errors are thrown when I try to fit the model, but it only works on the first batch of training. As soon as the second batch starts, the loss becomes 'nan'. Upon closer inspection, it seems like the LSTM layer is outputting 'nan' after the first epoch of training.

My two guesses for what is going on are:

1. I set up the masking layer wrong, and it for some reason fails to mask out all of the -inf values after the first training iteration. Thus, -inf gets passed through the LSTM and it goes haywire.
2. I did something wrong with the format of my loss function, and the when the optimizer applies my calculated loss to the model it ruins the weights of the LSTM. For reference, my loss function outputs a 1D tensor with length equal to the number of samples in the batch. Each item in the output is a float with the loss of that sample.

I know that the math in my loss function is good since I've tested it on sample data, but maybe the output format is wrong even though it seems to match what I've found online.

Let me know if the problem is obvious from what I've shown or if you need more information.

Comment: pretty sure that using -inf is not the best choice, the gradient wrt infinity is pretty much always NaN (the only occasion where this is used, is for attention, to have 0 with the softmax)...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Should that still be a problem when I'm specifically trying to mask it out? If I change it to -10 or something instead my model might not break but it will get fed garbage inputs if the masking problem isn't solved.

Comment: Actually I just changed my data to be -10 instead of -inf and it still results in nan loss, so I have no clue what it is. It also results in nan loss when I set my learning rate to 0, so I don't think it could be my loss function feeding it bad values.

Comment: Found out more info about the issue, my loss function does seem to be the problem. Will post a more relevant question.

Comment: Sure, let me know what you have uploaded it, because as for know, I'm not able to reproduce your code

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73310558/