# Custom loss function returns correct values, but sets all of my model weights to nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, loss-function

I am attempting to train an LSTM with a custom loss function. The model's goal is to read in some sequential noisy points on a curve, and generate coefficients for an nth degree polynomial that fits the curve. The curve has multiple variables, x, y and z, that all depend on time. The model will generate one set of coefficients for each variable such that when plotted over time, the polynomial is a best fit for its respective set of points.

The reason I'm not using a more mathematical method to just fit a polynomial to a set of points is that I believe those methods will overfit to the noise in a given sample, whereas a model trained on thousands of samples will learn to generate curves that ignore noise. I may also choose to use a function other than polynomials in the future if they fit the problem better, and that change would be trivial for this model.

train_X is a tensor of shape (10000, 508, 3) where 508 is the maximum sequence length, sequences that aren't 508 long are front padded with -10.0.

train_y is a tensor of shape (10000, 100, 4). Every sequence in y is exactly 100 long, and is a downsample of the full curve being estimated. some sequences in X have more data, but they do not cover the entire curve being estimated. It has 4 values instead of 3 because the last one is time, and is used when calculating loss.

Here is my model definition (3 variables are being estimated with polynomials of degree 10):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=float(-10), 
    input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30), 
    kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((3, 10)))

model.compile(loss=batched_polynomial_loss, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())

model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_y, validation_data=val, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

And here is my loss function, where tf_power_outer is a helper function that replicates np.power.outer(). I couldn't use the numpy version and still train with eager execution off.

```
def tf_power_outer(elem):
    powers = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(polynomial_model_degree), dtype=tf.float32)
    expand_elem = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.full((polynomial_model_degree), 1.0), dtype=tf.float32)
    expanded_elem = tf.tensordot(expand_elem, elem, axes=0)
    expand_powers = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.full((100), 1.0), dtype=tf.float32)
    expanded_powers = tf.tensordot(powers, expand_powers, axes=0)
    return tf.pow(expanded_elem, expanded_powers)


def batched_polynomial_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    true_tracks = tf.transpose(y_true, [0, 2, 1])
    tt_shape = tf.shape(true_tracks)
    times = tf.slice(true_tracks, [0, tt_shape[1] - 1, 0], [tt_shape[0], 1, tt_shape[2]])
    times = tf.squeeze(times, axis=1)
    variables = tf.slice(true_tracks, [0, 0, 0], [tt_shape[0], tt_shape[1] - 1, tt_shape[2]])
    time_mats = tf.map_fn(tf_power_outer, times)
    guess_data = tf.matmul(y_pred, time_mats)
    mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
    full_error = mse(variables, guess_data)
    reduced_error = tf.math.reduce_mean(full_error, axis=1)
    return reduced_error
```

To summarize the loss function, it gets all of the times in the truth data, and plugs those times into polynomial equations created with the model's coefficients. It then compares all of the points generated by the polynomial equations to the actual points using mean squared error. The result of this mse call is shape (batch, num_variables), and so I call the tf.math.reduce_mean function to get this into shape (batch,) before returning.

When I call fit, the first batch seems to work just fine. Here is the tensor that the first loss function call returns:

> tf.Tensor(
> [0.43722156 0.43722296 0.43722203 0.43722162 0.4372231  0.43722177
> 0.43722287 0.4372219  0.43722144 0.43722153 0.43722144 0.43722233
> 0.43722257 0.43722162 0.4372209  0.4372227  0.43722272 0.437222
> 0.4372225  0.4372209  0.4372218  0.43722168 0.43722332 0.4372232
> 0.43722224 0.4372219  0.43722248 0.43722233 0.4372224  0.43722132
> 0.4372232  0.43722188], shape=(32,), dtype=float32)

This looks right to me, and the math in the loss function is correct. However, after a single training step, every single weight in my model gets set to nan. This does not stop the training, no errors are thrown, but after one step the model just returns nan, and the loss is therefore nan.

What's wrong with my loss function? I've tried different optimizers and very low learning rates, but it always gets set to nan. It's not the masking either, as I tried a model without masking and still got nan.

Let me know if you need anything else to reproduce this issue, but you should be able to just use placeholder values for train_X and train_y and plug them in.

Edit:
I've tried an output of shape (batch, 3, 10) to have 1 error value for every model output, but this still goes to nan.

Edit 2: I actually printed out what the loss function returns during training instead of a separate test, and it looks like this:

> Tensor("batched_polynomial_loss/Mean:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)

Is this correct? the "batched_polynomial_loss/Mean:0" thing is concerning to me, but the shape is correct assuming "None" means "batch size", which is usually does.

Edit 3: When training with a gradient tape this is what I get when printing the gradient:

> [<tf.Tensor: shape=(11, 128), dtype=float32, numpy= array([[0., 0.,
> 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> ...,
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(32, 128), dtype=float32, numpy= array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0.,
> 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> ...,
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=float32, numpy= array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(32, 64), dtype=float32, numpy= array([[0., 0., 0.,
> ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> ...,
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
> [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(64,), dtype=float32, numpy= array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 30), dtype=float32, numpy=
> array([[ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
> 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
> [ 6.7246698e-02, -4.2618643e+02, -9.2154006e+05, ...,
> -3.8224320e+22, -7.0191927e+25, -1.3077239e+29],
> [ 6.2223826e-02, -3.9435468e+02, -8.5271000e+05, ...,
> -3.5369330e+22, -6.4949257e+25, -1.2100493e+29],
> ...,
> [ 3.2375057e-03, -2.0518349e+01, -4.4366676e+04, ...,
> -1.8402735e+21, -3.3793236e+24, -6.2959127e+27],
> [ 1.7688489e-02, -1.1210295e+02, -2.4239945e+05, ...,
> -1.0054427e+22, -1.8463103e+25, -3.4398029e+28],
> [ 1.1006804e-01, -6.9757324e+02, -1.5083582e+06, ...,
> -6.2564830e+22, -1.1488879e+26, -2.1404574e+29]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(30,), dtype=float32, numpy=
> array([ 6.0670018e-01, -3.8450579e+03, -8.3141405e+06, -1.5660871e+10,
> -2.8943713e+13, -5.3658182e+16, -1.0029243e+20, -1.8912737e+23,
> -3.5962617e+26, -6.8893381e+29,  1.6471731e+01,  1.5045589e+04,
> 1.8590212e+07,  2.6241573e+10,  4.0149233e+13,  6.4911980e+16,
> 1.0927340e+20,  1.8970660e+23,  3.3739135e+26,  6.1173324e+29,
> -1.5370066e+01, -1.7797381e+04, -2.5041262e+07, -3.8708691e+10,
> -6.3491046e+13, -1.0852857e+17, -1.9123389e+20, -3.4486026e+23,
> -6.3327237e+26, -1.1798300e+30], dtype=float32)>]

This feels weird, only the last layer looks like it's getting any gradient, and a lot of the values in it have huge magnitudes. What's also weird is why do all of my weights get set to nan if most of the gradients are zero?

On the second pass of training with gradient tape, the shapes are the same as the first but all of the values are "nan".

Comment: try fitting your data with `GradientTape` and check the gradients

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia updated with the gradients, do they mean anything to you?

Comment: I can see a `-3.8224320e+22` which is ginormous... try using `keras.optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=1)` to clip the gradient

Comment: Yeah the values are huge, but I'm wondering how that even happens when the loss values I'm calculating are like 0.43? There seems to be something very wrong with how the loss is being fed through the gradient function for that to happen in the first place

Comment: Tried it with clipvalue, now on the second pass through not all of the gradients are nan, all of the first layer gradients are nan but the last layer has some inf, -inf, and huge values mixed in. By the third training step, the values are all nan again.

Comment: mh that's pretty strange, you might have something wrong with the loss, but it's not too clear what you are implementing... btw, loss value and gradients has nothing to do with them, infact loss+c will have the same exact gradient, thus you can have 0 loss and huge gradient

Comment: If gradient doesn't depend on loss what does it depend on? I thought that loss is what gets backpropagated through the weights to create a gradient, so it would be weird to have huge gradients with normal weights and small loss

Comment: the gradient describes how much the loss is sensitive to a small change of a specific weight... however, the value of the gradient and the value of the gradient have no strict relation (except for obvious, like MSE the greater the loss, the greater the gradient), but any loss plus any constant, does not change the gradient

Comment: So perhaps could there be nothing wrong, but my model is too sensitive? It's weird to me that the LSTM layer and first dense layer would have 0 sensitivity and the last dense layer would be insanely sensitive though...

Comment: No, the sensitivity is defined by the loss, for example `1/x` is very sensible to change of x if it's near 0... thus, the "sensitivity" usually depends on the loss, however RNN has a very well known problem known as vanishing/exploding gradient... the clip solves the exploding, LSTM were introduced to solve the vanishing...

Comment: you may want to debug your model, I would start by normalizing the input, and just using a 2 layer net with LSTM net and a Dense, if the problem still persist, then it's worth double checking the loss